# How to simulate db failures when unit testing

Tags: php, database, unit-testing, phpunit

I use phpUnit and write my tests involving databases by extending `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase`.
How do I simulate database failures to test my error checking? What kind of failures might occur that I should test, other than the db being down?

I found [this Ruby on Rails question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096478/how-to-simulate-database-failure-for-test-purposes-in-ruby-on-rails), but found it not to be relevant to phpUnit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I separate the code block, and then [use Mocks/Stubs in PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest8.php) to control the return from the database call to contain the error, so my main code will process the error.  I do not use the actual database, but test the code doing the interaction to handle the database errors either by Exceptions or what ever method your code expects.

To simulate the same return from your code with the mock, you would do the following:

```
$stub = $this->getMock('YourDBClass');

// Configure the stub to return an error when the RunQuery method is called
$stub->expects($this->any())
     ->method('RunQuery')
     ->will($this->throwException(new SpecificException));
```

You can test using either the [@expectsException](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions)

```
/**
 * @expectedException SpecificException
 */
public function testDBError()
{
    $stub = $this->getMock('YourDBClass');

    // Configure the stub to return an error when the RunQuery method is called
    $stub->expects($this->any())
         ->method('RunQuery')
         ->will($this->throwException(new SpecificException));

    $stub->RunQuery();  
}
```

or using the setExpectedException

```
public function testDBError()
{
    $stub = $this->getMock('YourDBClass');

    // Configure the stub to return an error when the RunQuery method is called
    $stub->expects($this->any())
         ->method('RunQuery')
         ->will($this->throwException(new SpecificException));

    $this->setExpectedException('SpecificException');
    $stub->RunQuery();  
}
```

You would then test known returns the same way

```
public function testDBQueryReturns1()
{
    $stub = $this->getMock('YourDBClass');

    // Configure the stub to return an error when the RunQuery method is called
    $stub->expects($this->any())
         ->method('RunQuery')
         ->will($this->returnValue(1));

    $this->assertEquals(1, $stub->RunQuery(), 'Testing for the proper return value');
}
```